# UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, NO, -1);

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, quartz-graphics

Does anyone know what happens if I set a -1 to the scale fator in this function?

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, NO, -1);
 _cacheImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
[_cacheImage drawInRect:[self bounds]];

NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(_cacheImage, 0);

NSLog(@"%i", data.length);


NSData *data = UIImage
```

If I use -1, I cannot get a UIImageJPEGRepresentation, but the drawInRect works ok. What could be going on?
Also whe using -1 my app uses a lot less memory (confirmed in instruments)

Answer (score 1):

Negative scaling factors do not have a documented or defined behavior in the documentation.

Comment: Do you know if my app can get rejected int the app store by doing this call?

Comment: I honestly don't know. They don't say what valid ranges are, they just mention values like 1.0, 2.0, 1.5, etc..

Answer (score 0):

Got this from the apple forums:

> The scale must be non-negative or you don't get a valid context. I
>   suspect this is the reason why you are using less memory (we didn't
>   setup a context) and you aren't getting a JPEG (because there is
>   nothing to get). The console log should have a message to that effect
>   as well I believe. - Rincewind